# C# .net 2.0 webservice is slow at first call

Tags: c#, web-services

Client Site: Windows form

Server Site: .net 2.0 asmx. IIS 7, wins 2008 R2.

First Call Defination: IIS Restarted or app pool recycled.

The first call to web service hosted in IIS is alwasy slow, it takes around 20 plus seconds.

subsequent calls are quick, less than 1 second. A fresh instance of client app also perform same (quick).

I have set the useDefaultWebProxy = false, bypassProxyOnLocal = true at client app.config which i understand from variuos sources in internet.

I did a testing by running the client app(first call to webservice) in Client PC, and as expected it is slow. and then i ran the client app(2nd call to webservice) in Server PC, it is quick.

This is true at the other way round, if the client app get executed in Server first(first call, it's slow), the second time running the Client App(2nd calls) in client PC is quick.

From the above scenerio, im trying to say that the network proxy might not be the issue here..

I've set the "Generete serialization assembly" to On as well at the Properties of the web service project.

Is there anyway to improve this?

Comment: You probably have to warm up (preload) the web application that hosts your service. See the Web Applications section in [ASP.NET Performance Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668225.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There may be multiple causes to slow initialization. Most notably:

- Application is prepared and any templates are cached if they exist (this shouldn't be an issue unless you have web pages in your project also)
- Other libraries take time to initialize. Particularly, look into performance of database connections. Entity Framework comes to mind. It takes some time to compile, generate and cache queries first time a query runs. Subsequent queries are faster.

In case you are using EntityFramework, my only recommendation is to update version of Entity Framework, which will require you to also use newer version of .NET.

Answer (score 0):

For the first request, the IIS will have to wake up (or initialize) some process to handle the request, that results a long time for first response.

The easier and most common approach is to endure the first time, and ping your site periodically to keep those processes awaken. There are some good Ping Services out there I think.